# Issue with the notify Method

Tags: java

```
class Thread1 extends Thread {

    int x;

    synchronized public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "=====" + x);
            x++;
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

---

```
public class Wait {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread1 thrd = new Thread1();
        Thread b = new Thread(thrd);
        b.setName("Vishesh");
        b.start();
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        synchronized (thrd) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("notified.....");
                thrd.notify();

            }

        }

        System.out.println("end of main");
    }    
}
```

Console output----

```
Vishesh=====0
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
notified.....
Hi
mainend of main
Vishesh=====1
```

on console I am able to see that it has notified 10 times but on each notify ... why it did't print the count.

Answer (score 1):

`notify()` doesn't release the lock. The waiting thread can only wake up when the notifying thread goes out of the synchronized section. But it doesn't:

```
synchronized (thrd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("notified.....");
        thrd.notify();
    }
}
```

You're notifying, but don't go out of the synchronized section and keep looping. So the waiting thread can only wake up after the 10th notify() call has been made and the notifying thread has finished looping.

Just a couple of additional notes:

- your Thread1 class shouldn't extend Thread, but implement Runnable
- you'd better use a shared lock between your threads rather than using the runnable itself as lock.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have one more doubt.. if I would change my code like -- synchronized (thrd) {

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("notified.....");
    thrd.notify();
    thrd.wait(8);
   }

  } 
it is working fine and output will be.. why so..

Vishesh=====0
notified.....
Vishesh=====1
notified.....
Vishesh=====2
notified.....
Vishesh=====3
notified.....
Vishesh=====4
notified.....
Vishesh=====5
notified.....
Vishesh=====6
notified.....
Vishesh=====7
notified.....
Vishesh=====8
notified.....
Vishesh=====9
notified.....
end of main

Comment: Read the javadoc. wait() releases the lock.